# How to find all lines with character occuring more than x times, Notepad++?

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have what most of you will probably consider a trivially easy problem to solve.

I have a list which is formatted like so;

```
?d?d?d?d?l?d?d?d
?d?d?d?d?l?d?d?l
?d?d?d?d?l?d?d?u
?d?d?d?d?l?d?l?d
?d?d?d?d?l?d?l?l
```

There are many tens of thousands of lines like this. I would like a regular expression that will select all of the lines that contain more than 5 occurrences of the letter `d` so they can be removed from the list.

Despite searching extensively, I have not found a solution that works. I've found many ways of searching for occurrences of characters etc. on this and other forums (including spaces and special characters), and have been able to successfully conduct the search on other lists of words but I think the presence of all those question marks screws it up... I can't say for sure though.

I apologise in advance if I somehow missed a post which explains this perfectly, but I have made an effort to find a solution on my own and have just become exasperated with it.

Many thanks in advance for any help provided!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use Find and Replace and replace lines matching the following with nothing:

```
^.*(d.*){6}.*\r\n
```

Explanation:

- `^` - start at beginning of a line
- `.*` - skip 0 or more uninteresting characters but not past end of line
- `(d.*)` - find d followed by any uninteresting characters but not past end of line
- `{6}` - repeat the last group exactly six times (so 6 (d followed by anything)) (use `{6,}` for 6 or more)
- `.*` - match any remaining characters up to end of line
- `\r\n` - match end of line sequence (as pointed out by @toto, better as `\R`)

See https://regex101.com/r/UaYAz4/1

Update based on comments:

```
^[^d\r\n]*(d[^d\r\n]*){6,}.*\R
```

Comment: Amazing, that seems to have worked... Didn't work on the online sandbox though, oddly. 

Thanks for your help!!

Comment: You have to be careful with online evaluators, there are many Regex engines and you must make sure to pick a matching one, plus in your case end of line in Notepad++ is \r\n (because Windows) but other systems may use \n (Unix/Linux/Mac) or even \r.

Comment: Why not use $ to match the end of the line. Also, this matches exactly 6 occurrences.

Comment: This kind of pattern will quickly end in a catastrophic backtracking, you need to rewrite it using negated character classes.

Comment: @3ocene Because `$` is a zero length match, so when you do a Replace, you will end up with a bunch of blank lines instead of removing the lines.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte It was a little slow when I ran it against 132,000 line file, but it reduced it to 70,929 lines in less than a minute. It took Notepad++ a while to undo the replace, so I don't think the performance is an RE problem.

Comment: The sandbox is probably why I've spent so long on this problem and I haven't learned a great deal about regular expressions as a result... I will be wary of those sandbox sites in future! Anyone care to elaborate on this solution for future reference? It's awesome that it worked, but I'd like to know exactly why.

Comment: They aren't all bad, just something to be aware of, especially when dealing with line endings. I added an explanation and a link to a regex101 that also automatically provides an explanation.

Answer (score 1):

Without having notepad++ installed, I would expect [`^.*(?:d.*){5,}$` (regex101)](https://regex101.com/r/zGgi8p/1) to do what you want:

- `^` start at the start of the line.
- `.*` match any character 0 or more times. (Ignore any characters that aren't `d` at the start of the line.)
- `(?:d.*){5,}` Match the following 5 or more times:

  - `d` the letter d.
  - `.*` any character 0 or more times. (Ignore any characters between the `d`s.)
- `$` match the end of the line.

As NetMage pointed out, this will leave blank lines. To fix this, use `\r?\n` instead of `$`. This matches:

- `\r?` an optional carriage return if using windows.
- `\n` a line break.

Comment: "more than 5 occurrences" :) Nice use of the optional `\r`, though perhaps `[\r\n]{1,2}` would be more to the point.

Comment: @NetMage That would match `\n\n` which could remove a blank line.

Comment: It' better to use `\R` that matches any kind of linebreak, `\r` or `\n` or `\r\n`

Comment: @Toto Nice Notepad++ feature!